# I'm having problems understanding the syntax of conditionals in R

Tags: r

I'm try to creating a program that tallies the total amount of occurrences that a number has in a dataframe. However the code i'm running gives me errors like:

Error: unexpected '}' in:" C_bin2++}" or Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Originally that data was read in from file but I just wrote it all out to demonstrate. Also a large portion of the code was left out because it was repetitive but you'll get the gist of what I'm trying to do. Please help me understand the problem. Thank you!

```
x_axis = c(94.5,   22.5,   69.0, -145.5,   13.5, -186.0,  -79.0,  -47.0,  -15.0,  -72.5,   27.0,    6.0,   84.5,   -9.0,
-21.5   ,60.5,   40.5, -316.5,  -61.5,   54.5,   -3.5,   -7.0,  -38.5,  -30.5,  -20.5,   41.0,  -58.0,  -21.0,
12.0    ,5.0   ,34.0  , 29.0   ,61.0,  -52.5 ,-43.5)

hr6_distance = data.frame(x_axis)

C_bin1 = c()
C_bin2 = c()
C_bin3 = c()
C_bin4 = c()
C_bin5 = c()
C_bin6 = c()
C_bin7 = c()
C_bin8 = c()
C_bin9 = c()
C_bin10 = c()
C_bin11 = c()
C_bin12 = c()
C_bin13 = c()
C_bin14 = c()
C_bin15 = c()
C_bin16 = c()
C_bin17 = c()


for (col in 1:nrow(hr6_distance))
{ 
  if (hr6_distance[col] > 500) 
  {
    C_bin1++
  } else if ((x_axis <= 500) && (x_axis < 400)) 
  {
      C_bin2++
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output you are looking for?

Comment: Just for examples sake lets was that there were 2 450's in that vector up top. Then C_bin2 to have a value of 2

Comment: R doesn't have a `++` operator. You'd need to do `C_bin1 <- C_bin1+1`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are planning to do but I assume you want to assign the C_bin1, C_bin2 vectors according to your condition if then you can try below:

```
#iterate through the data frame
for (col in 1:nrow(hr6_distance))
{
  #get the column 
  value = hr6_distance[col, ][1]
  #check for the condition 
  if (value > 500) {
    #add it to the vacto C_bin1
    C_bin1[length(C_bin1) + 1] = value
    
    
    
  } else if (value <= 500 & value > 400) {
    #add it to the vacto C_bin2
    C_bin2[length(C_bin2) + 1] = value
    
  }
}
```

Once it creates the vectors if you need the count you can use

```
length(C_bin1)
length(C_bin2)
```

to get the length of each vector.